# Dynamically show a nested list item using contains in jquery

Tags: jquery

i have a ul list that contains nested ul items. Based on what page the user is on, i want to show the nested list of that particular page. I have some code i've used in the past that works on another site, but can't quite figure out why it's not working here. Here is the jquery i'm using:

```
var pName = 'In The News';

$('#subNav ul ul').hide();

$("#subNav li:contains('"+pName.replace('&amp;','&')+"')").parents('ul').show();

$("#subNav li:contains('"+pName.replace('&amp;','&')+"')").children('ul').show();
```

Not sure why it doesn't work. Another pair of eyes would be awesome. Thanks all... here's my jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/grem28/MN69c/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`children()` is for direct descendants only. Use `find()` instead here because your structure is actually li > div > ul.

http://jsfiddle.net/DFDdL/

Additionally, I would change the code to run that selector once and save the result to a variable, since it looks expensive.

Comment: also, how would i put the selected in a variable and change the code?